# css word wrapping alignment in a list

Tags: html, css, list

I am making a list to act as a table. I know i could use a table to do the same job, But tables really bloat code. 
The thing is, if the text is too long the next line goes under the position of the  *1st* cell location. Instead i want it to align with the *2nd* cell. I tried fooling around with heights, and widths, and floats. but i can't seem to get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/dpp2P/1/

Desired Look:

```
/*
9001     This is a long wrapping sentence. This is a long wrapping sentence. This 
         is along wrapping sentence. This is a long wrapping sentence.

9002     test test test.

9003     I need this to line up as if it were a table.

9004     Except that tables bloat your code.

9005     So i want to use css and lists instead.
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:table-cell` to your `right`class:

```
.right{       
    display:table-cell;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ub58/1/

Comment: Thank you very much, This was just was i was looking for; clear and concise.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<div>`s, or just set your spans to block level. Then you can add border/margin/padding to acheive your desired spacing between cells.

Also, the whole fuzz about tables is using them where the thing being displayed is *not* a table. Using them is no problem if you want to display tabular data.

http://jsfiddle.net/dpp2P/2/

## Changes:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="list">9001</div> <div class="right"> This is a long wrapping sentence. This is a long wrapping sentence. This is a long wrapping sentence. This is a long wrapping sentence.</div></li>
    <li><div class="list">9002</div> <div class="right">test test test</div></li>
    <li><div class="list">9003</div> <div class="right">I need this to line up as if it were a table</div></li>
    <li><div class="list">9004</div> <div class="right">Except that tables bloat your code.</div></li>
    <li><div class="list">9005</div> <div class="right">So i want to use css and lists instead</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.right{
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, But i am trying not to bloat the code, this one has a lot of extra syntax which does just that.

Comment: What? I just changed `span` to `div`, actually shortening the code by 4 characters each line. and the only CSS I've changed is the `width` property, with 1 more character.

Comment: I know, but the code i fiddled was an example., my real code is in asp and it doesn't have any <span> tags, I added them here to emulate what i had. The above answer was less clutter, just 1 change in a css class that already existed.

Answer (score 0):

i do not see you using `display:table / table-cell;`
 if `<li>` are displayed as `table`, or `table-row` and `<ul>` as `table`, `<span>` can be displayed as `table-cell`;

http://jsfiddle.net/dpp2P/7/ or http://jsfiddle.net/dpp2P/8/